# Hibernated Windows Desktop starts unexpectedly

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hibernate

In my Windows XP desktop computer I select "Hibernate" option and computer closes itself. Then I don't use computer (for example I go out, or spend time in other rooms etc.) for hours. When I go back to computer I see that computer is started from Hibernated state.

But I didn't press Power button. What would be the cause that opens computer and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Do you have Wake-On-Lan enabled in the BIOS, and is a network cable connected to the computer? Could be that it thinks it has received a wake-up signal via the NIC.

Comment: Sometimes it could be the mouse which moves and wakes it up. Do you use a wireless mouse? Try switching it off before entering hibernate mode?

Comment: Sometimes the Antivirus which tries to make an update wakes the computer from hibernation. Is it at a specific time only or random times?